# Python - calling function from terminal on thousands of text files - 5000 files limit?

Tags: python, terminal

I am calling a python function from console using the following command:

```
printf '%s\0' *.txt | xargs -0 python ./functionName.py
```

I have almost 10500 text files in the directory I want to process.

For every file processed, I print the file number and the total number of files:

```
cnt=0
for f in sys.argv[1:]:
    cnt=cnt+1
    print "Processing file ", cnt, " of : ", len(sys.argv[1:])
```

Using this, I see that `len(sys.argv[1:]` is 5000, and then it starts again for another 5000, and finally for the remaining 500 files.

Finally, I want to write for each text file I process some key variables on a `.csv` file

```
writer.writerow([var1, var2, var3, ... , varN])
```

The problem I have is that only the variables of only the last 500 files are written..

I suspect it has to do with `len(sys.argv[1:]` being 5000 although it should be 10500..

I know there is something wrong with the number of files, since it works for less files..

Is there some limit to 5000?

Can I fix this somehow?

Comment: Have you tried assigning `len(...)` to some variable and then using it in `print`? `sys.argv` may vary from time to time.

Comment: just tried still prints `5000`

Comment: My guess is that this is a more fundamental limitation on command line arguments either in your UNIX system or in your `xargs`. I'd suggest either reading filenames from a file or STDIN instead of the command line if there are so many.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually one of the *features* of `xargs`: it splits large inputs into multiple invocations of the command it is supposed to call (see the [xargs manual page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=xargs&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%209.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html)). The default maximum number for arguments is 5000, so `xargs` calls your program 3 times: with 5000, 5000 and 500 file names as arguments. You can modify the `xargs` setting for the number of arguments per invocation using the `-n` option.

Said that, I doubt that passing 10500 file names as command line arguments is a  very good idea. You should use Python's facilities for scanning the file system in the way you want. In your case, it is a matter of using the [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module. For example like so:

```
import glob

for filename in glob.glob("*.txt"): ...
```